# How to make chat box on specific location on page when i click on button dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i want this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzgFP.png)

but this working like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBvqF.png)
It create but it is appear bottom on page I need to scroll down to reach it..
I want that it appear on the page that is display on the screen

following is my code

```
var div = $("<div>", {
  // "text":"I'm a new paragraph!",
  "class": "bat",
  "css": {
    "background": "#f7f7f7",
    "height": "350",
    "border": "10px solid #33A919",
    "width": "250px",
    "float": "right",
    "position": "relative",
    "top": "20vh",
    "border-top-left-radius": "10px",
    "border-top-right-radius": "10px"
  }
});
$("body").append(div);

$("<div>", {
  "class": "foo",
  "text": "Heading my name is khan",
  "css": {
    "color": "white",
    "background": "#33A919",
    "height": "30px",
    "line-height": "30px"
  }

}).appendTo(".bat");

$(".foo").after("<div class='msg' style='background: hotpink;height:250px;width: 250px;overflow-y: auto;'></div>");
$(".msg").after("<textarea placeholder='Type your message here!' style='background: white; height: 65px; width: 250px; margin-top: 4px;'></textarea>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position:fixed`

```
"position": "fixed",
"bottom": "0",
"right": "0",
```

Demo

```js
var div = $("<div>", {
  // "text":"I'm a new paragraph!",
  "class": "bat",
  "css": {
    "background": "#f7f7f7",
    "height": "350",
    "border": "10px solid #33A919",
    "width": "250px",
    "float": "right",
    "position": "fixed",
    "bottom": "0",
    "right": "0",
    "border-top-left-radius": "10px",
    "border-top-right-radius": "10px"
  }
});
$("body").append(div);

$("<div>", {
  "class": "foo",
  "text": "Heading my name is khan",
  "css": {
    "color": "white",
    "background": "#33A919",
    "height": "30px",
    "line-height": "30px"
  }

}).appendTo(".bat");

$(".foo").after("<div class='msg' style='background: hotpink;height:250px;width: 250px;overflow-y: auto;'></div>");
$(".msg").after("<textarea placeholder='Type your message here!' style='background: white; height: 65px; width: 250px; margin-top: 4px;'></textarea>");
```

```css
body{height:800px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ewwink you are legend problem solved...But Please little bit explained i cant unserstand clearly....

Comment: you're welcome. it long to explain, to better understand you can read about css positioning on https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp